# jQuery ASCX and Postback

Tags: jquery, postback, ascx

I must be missing something here.
I have an ASCX control, containing a couple of textboxes and an asp:button.
i am loading the ASCX using JqueryUI Dialog as below:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display: none">
   <mycontrols:controlabc runat="server" id="abc" />
</div>
```

With Jquery:

```
var dialog = $("#myDiv").dialog({
         width: 700,
         height: 300,
         modal: true,
         autoOpen: false
});

dialog.parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
dialog.dialog("open");
```

Dialog displays correctly, however, i cannot perform a postback by clicking the button insdie the control.
If i take the fields inside the ASCX out of it, and into the ... all works correctly.

It seems the ASCX is not being moved into the form:first.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var dialog = $("#myDiv").dialog({
    width: 700,
    height: 300,
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function(type, data) {
        $(this).parent().appendTo("form:first");
    }
});
```

And you are not inside `UpdatePanel`, right?